# An issue with displaying post system regarding AJAX usage

Tags: php

So, I have this system where you can make a post. So, how it works is, there is an input field, whatever you type in the input field, and click post, it will send to the database as en entry and get posted. The post will be displayed. However, with my current system, after entering something in the input field, and clicking post, the entry gets sent to the database, but the post doesn't actually display. For it to display, you need to refresh the page again, which it displays then, and two entries go to the database.

I don't want this to happen. Right when the user enters text into the input field and clicks post, the post should display on the go, you shouldn't have to refresh for the post to be displayed, and only one entry should be sent to the database, not two. Now, I also included my database connection and my insert statements, but here is the code to display the post:

```
<div class="textPost">
  <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  ?>
  <div class="textpostFormat">
    // all the displayed post content
  </div>
  <?php

  }
}

  ?>
</div>
```

Insert Statement (post.php):

```
<?php

session_start();

// Making Connection To The Database

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "root";
$database = "feed";

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $database) or die ("Sorry, we could not connect to the database");

// Posting System

if (!empty($_POST['postContent'])) {
  $post = $_POST['postContent'];
  $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (firstname, lastname, body, date_posted) VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
  // nested if statement
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $firstname, $lastname, $post);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  }
} else {
  echo "";
}

?>
```

So, since PHP is a server side language, to make the calls, you would require AJAX to accomplish this problem/situation. The only problem is, I don't know what the AJAX would be. **So my question is, for this particular situation, what would the AJAX be?** I don't want any tutorials, just the code. Also, I can't try on some AJAX code and ask for help, because I don't even know what it would be in the first place. I don't want to use the PHP approach to solve this problem, I want the AJAX approach, and for that, the AJAX code to solve this situation.

So, please, please spare a few minutes of your time to answer this question. Please. Thanks a lot! I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: If you don't want a php solution you shouldn't only provide PHP code and tag your question as PHP. But the right move is to have your javascript code either refresh the page after receiving the sucess answer to your ajax call; or have the answer include the actual html for the new post and inject that into the DOM.

Comment: @Raxi So what is the AJAX code? Could you provide me with it?

Comment: No, that'd be specific to your usecase. There is no one size fits all approach.

Comment: But can you provide some AJAX code according to my case. I provided the necessary requirements already in my question (the codes).